# Interpretation of BIOS-screenprint (SATA-part)

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, bios, sata

I have a Tyan Tempest S2696 i5000xt motherboard in my home-made server. The board has 6 physical SATA-connectors and I think 2 of them are not connected to anything - so that leaves 4 connectors. When going into the bios I get the following screen - see attached screenprint. It says "SATA Port 1" "SATA Port 2" and then again "SATA Port 1" and "SATA Port 2". Obviously there is one entry here for each of the 4 physical connectors. But why does it not say "SATA Port 1", "SATA Port 2", "SATA Port 3", "SATA Port 4"? Does it have to do with two physical ports connected to the same controller, or something like that? Any insights on this would be very interesting.[screen-shot of BIOS of my Tyan Tempest i5000xt S2696 motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl64T.jpg)

Comment: According to your motherboard's manual, you have a SATA and a SAS controller on that board so I'd check if any of the drives is connected to a port that is handled from the other controller. Swapping ports around could show you that.
Also, you have RAID support on the motherboard so I would check if you have any RAID mode activated that may be causing this.

Comment: Actually, I think the motherboard comes in several variants - one with SAS, one without. On my board the SAS connectors are removed. So I do not think my board supports SAS.

Comment: It could have been something with the RAID. However, I have checked the manual and the BIOS of my system, and RAID is disabled. And all connected disks show up independently. So I do not think I have any RAID mode activated.

Comment: In this case try to clear the BIOS either by the manual's instructions or by removing the CMOS battery for about a minute. This will reset the BIOS settings and anything that may be causing this. Otherwise you can always contact the manufacturer's support and ask if this is a known situation and get some help from them.